# Proving a limit of function doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus

How can i prove that the function $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)^2 }{x^3 }$ has no limit as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ has a limit. What are you then left with?

Comment: yes i see this now - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If you have meant  $\frac{(\sin x)^2}{x^3},$

$$\frac{(\sin x)^2}{x^3}=\frac1x\cdot\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2$$

Or if you have meant, $\frac{\sin x^2}{x^3}$

$$\frac{\sin x^2}{x^3}=\frac1x\cdot\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}$$

Do you know, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=??$

Comment: Thank you very much - ill try to think about this now.  By the way, how do you write mathematical expressions like that? I think i just managed to prove what i needed to - thank you very much!

Comment: I have meant the first case. And yes i know the limit you mentioned and i think i can now solve this problem :)

Comment: @ArielFerdman, my pleasure

Comment: Im really sorry i cant vote up your Answer since i don't have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @ArielFerdman, it's nice to hear that you could solve the rest

Comment: basically i showed that from both sides of zero the limits of the multiplication of these functions are once positive infinity and once negative infinity hence no limit at zero. Hope i got it right :) and thank you again :)